# Is my database design consistent with RDMS

Tags: python-3.x, database-design, relational-database, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on my website where I sell concert tickets.
I am working on designing the part of the website where I generate tickets based on seat and rows available.

After some thinking and drawing I have to the conclusion that this design would be best for my problem.
[image]

I was wondering is this poor design or are there any improvements that I can make?
Thank you

Comment: What about a bookings table? I expect you will need to record certain details about bookings (e.g. date of booking, address, payment details). It would seem to make sense to put the customer id in a bookings table rather than the seats table.

Comment: Ah yes I totally overlooked that. Thank you for reminding me, so instead should I have a Booking table that grabs the id of the Concert_Seats table. E.g. Booking{Customer_Id, Concert_Seats, Payment, Address, Date_Of_Purchase}?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Please clarifiy via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect to have a table of unbooked seats. A table of bookings seems more logical. Your concerts table looks questionable if you expect to have a series of dates for the same concert.

Perhaps you should first sketch out the key functions of your site as User Stories or Use Cases and list out the required attributes for each. That could give you a better set of requirements for your database design, e.g. what customer attributes; what about seat attributes such as restricted view, standing places or accessible places for the disabled.